# Split content database by creating new site collections

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, content-database

Im having one site collection with 5 sub sites utilizing very high space on the content database. Is it possible to move these sites by creating new site collections to different content databases? Will this lead to any design related issues since the master page is same for all the sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with using the export and import Sp-web

1. Export the subsite using [export-spweb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx)
2. create a new content Database
3. Create a new site collection with blank template `New-SPSite http:///sites/test -OwnerAlias "DOMAIN\JDoe" -ContentDatabase WSS_New_Site`
4. Now import the subsite on that new site collection using [Import-Spweb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx)
5. Now test.

Keep in mind there are limitation in export/import operation.

Easy method is use the 3rd party tools then move the subsites to new site collections. You can try Sharegate or metalogix etc.(both offer free trial)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All sites are Team sites with multiple features enabled: Bulk Workflow, Search, Publishing, CoSign Connector to name a few. Is it feasible to do export and import? Is there any alternate methods apart from third party tools.

Comment: import& export is the only option but it has limitation regaring workflows etc...

Answer (score 1):

Your in-box options are using `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb`. However, those options are not full fidelity and do not support sites with Publishing features enabled.

I would instead look at 3rd party solutions. Or reconsider... how large is the database and what is the concern? Out of disk space on the SQL Server?

Comment: no, the both commands works well even publishing features are enabled. only thing is it needs a site collection with blank template.

Comment: It's absolutely *not supported* to Export or save a Publishing-enabled site as a template.

Comment: i think you didnt get it right! export doesn't give you any template, it generates ".cab" files so those can be imported.

Comment: Again, well aware of that and how doing so with a Publishing site is *not supported*. Working != supported.

Comment: never heard of that, can you share any links that explains thats. i can only see the below: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh292621(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968483. This explicitly covers what the original poster is attempting to do (take a publishing subsite to a rootweb in a new Site Collection) which also outlines @waqas-sarwar-mvp answer is unsupported. But again, I don't like the `Export-SPWeb` answer due to all of the manual fix-ups that would be required. Instead, I'd focus on the database size concern the op has as it is likely a non-issue.

Comment: Publishing features are there for the mentioned sites. Is there any alternate methods?

Comment: Use a 3rd party Content Migration tool. My personal favorite is Sharegate, but any other tool should be viable.